# Inserting variable form data using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

sorry if this is very basic, but I've been going around in circles for a while. I'm new to PHP, but none of the documentation seems to help, and none of the previous questions on here quite explain it.

I'm trying to create a simple form that takes user input and creates a record in a database, but the code I have does not seem to recognise the variables provided. When I use strings instead, the insert operation completes, so I know it's not a problem with the connection.

I don't get any error messages - the page refreshes as though nothing had happened.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="new_word" id="word" required="required"/>
    <input type="text" name="book_ref" id="book" required="required"/>
    <input type="text" name="page_range" id="page" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "database";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `words` (`Word`, `Book ID`, `Page`) 
VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param(1, $word);
    $stmt->bind_param(2, $book);
    $stmt->bind_param(3, $page);
    $word = $_POST["new_word"];
    $book = $_POST["book_ref"];
    $page = $_POST["page_range"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: getting values after insert query? put your `$word` etc variables before `$stmt`

Comment: you have to define these variables $word,$book ,$page   after this condition if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write it like this:

`$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['new_word'], $_POST['book_ref'], $_POST['page_range']);`

It will insert each element without creating superfluous variables, and since it seems all the POST-content is from text fields, they're all strings. If there are digits only, you can change the corresponding `s` to a `d`

Comment: Ah! Yes! That did it. I don't know why that did it, but it did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the variables before you use them.

Your code should look like this:

```
$word = $_POST["new_word"];
$book = $_POST["book_ref"];
$page = $_POST["page_range"];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `words` (`Word`, `Book ID`, `Page`) 
VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $word, $book, $name);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You could change `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $word, $book, $name);` to just `$stmt->execute([$word, $book, $name]);` to make life a little simpler ^_^

Comment: @Option Good idea, I've added this to my answer.

Comment: @Option Just out of interest, which out of the two methods are more safe from SQL Injection, or are they both the same?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix it. I've tried the code exactly as you wrote it, and also tried putting the variable definition right after the IF statement opens, but no luck!

Comment: @Option you could refrain from commenting until you learn to read the question and the answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I passed on additional info that TheCodesee could add into his answer. My addition isn't incorrect it would just further input for his reponse.

Comment: @Luke Please add `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` after `$stmt->execute();` and submit the form and let me know if it returns any errors.

Comment: @Option you could pass additional ideas only if you have an idea what are you talking about.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, so my additional info was incorrect? Strangely... I picked up using $execute([$var]); from your PDO blog...

Comment: @Option and where can we see any trace of PDO here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign values first and then use them.

```
$word = $_POST["new_word"];
$book = $_POST["book_ref"];
$page = $_POST["page_range"];    

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `words` (`Word`, `Book ID`, `Page`) 
VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param(1, $word);
$stmt->bind_param(2, $book);
$stmt->bind_param(3, $page);



$stmt->execute();

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="new_word" id="word" required="required"/>
<input type="text" name="book_ref" id="book" required="required"/>
<input type="text" name="page_range" id="page" required="required"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "pass";
  $dbname = "database";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
$word = $_POST["new_word"];
$book = $_POST["book_ref"];
$page = $_POST["page_range"];
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `words` (`Word`, `Book ID`, `Page`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param(1, $word);
$stmt->bind_param(2, $book);
$stmt->bind_param(3, $page);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->close();
}
?>
```